# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, python-3.6, urllib

I am trying to open the Instagram URL using urllib.request.urlopen(url).read() but I am getting the error **urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway**

```py
username = input('enter the username - ')
url = "https://www.instagram.com/{}".format(username)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

How can I solve this issue?

EDIT:
I got the solution and I have posted it. Cheers :)

Comment: What are you entering for `username`?

Comment: I am entering a string, typically a valid Instagram username

Comment: @DebdutGoswami, hey did you find a solution to this? If yes please can you share that, we are facing the same issue...

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add
 `req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})`
then type
 `html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()`
 This will solve the problem. Previously it couldn't verify the origin of the request. We tricked it into thinking that the request is made from a genuine browser, i.e. Mozilla.