# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Cannot find server

Tags: python-3.x, tweepy, woe-id

I am tring to fetch woeid through location. Using Python 3.8 but its throw error: raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Cannot find server.

```
import tweepy
import twitter
import yweather
consumerKey = "jbdfkjds"
consumerSecret = "sdfkjdjkf"
accessToken = "hide"
accessTokenSecret = "hidden"
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#woeid finder
client = yweather.Client()
wid = client.fetch_woeid("USA")
print(wid)
```

Error Code:
[here is my terminal Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRZvC.png)

Please tell me why is it throwing error and how i solve this error????

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59088054/8928244

Comment: double check, the cause for this error may be: Webserver overload, Firewall blockage, And extension interuption

Comment: I don't know, how i can implement???. I have already check and delete unnecessary cookies in Crome browser. please clear me more.